# Alert or automatically fix code formatting attempts to use ''' instead of ```

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Lately I've been fixing a few questions per day where a new user made an effort to format their code properly but instead of using three backticks they used three apostrophes.

Needless to say, code formatted as:

'''
let comment = "Wrong format"
'''

doesn't format as nicely as:

```
let comment = "Correct format"
```

It would be nice if the user could be alerted to this mistake while editing or attempting to submit their question. Maybe even offer a way to automatically change the incorrect markup attempt.

As a side note, I'm curious why this seems to be a fairly new problem.

Comment: Probably due to the introduction of support for code fences.

Comment: We can’t do anything if the users can’t even check the preview of their question that the code blocks are rendered nicely. Guided mode also tells them to use `` and the info tab beside.

Comment: "*It would be nice if the user could be alerted to this mistake while editing or attempting to submit their question*" how would you even know that's incorrect? If you have something with the power to undestand what part of free *text* is supposed to be code, then it seems like you don't need any of the formatting tools and markup, as you can feed it to that system and it would just format it for you.

Comment: @VLAZ It's pretty simple to check if an even number of lines begin with `'''` and then alert that user that it appears they mistakenly used apostrophes instead of backticks.

Comment: _"Three apostrophes."_ is wrong, any way. Indent the code.

Comment: @Cerbrus Click on "Ask Question". Click in the question field (as opposed to the title). Now look at the editing help shown to the right. It's clearly showing the use of triple backticks for code fences. But apparently some users get confused and think they are apostrophes.

Comment: @rmaddy: Well there's the problem. Just tell them to indent code. It's something every programmer does all the time...

Answer (score 2):

It's rather complicated (impossible?) to detect whether or not the quotes were intentional.

I'd rather not see another one of these every time it thinks I'm about to do something:

[image]

Preferably, I'd see the ```` ``` ```` suggestion replaced with the instruction to ***indent*** code, as programmers do all the time, already.

Especially considering the fact that the [**help page**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that the hint links to, gives conflicting instructions:
It tells the user to *"Indent four spaces to create an escaped <pre> <code> block:"*.

Comment: Also, [`<pre> <code>` sometimes hide content](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26477048/revisions). That was a surprise.